# How to get Ant Design Option value and pass it into POST in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, select, axios

I haven't found anything jet that satisfies my needs. I would want to access my Ant Design Select item value and pass it into POST but somehow i get error as shown below:

> Cannot read property 'sport' of null

should i change my onChange method or what could be issue in my case?

My Form.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Input, Button, Select } from "antd";

import axios from "axios";

const FormItem = Form.Item;

const { Option } = Select;

function handleChange(value) {
  console.log(`selected ${value}`);
}


class CustomForm extends React.Component {

    handleFormSubmit = (event, requestType, trainingID) => {
        const title = event.target.elements.title.value;
        const content = event.target.elements.content.value;
        const organizeremail = event.target.elements.organizeremail.value;
        const sport = this.state.sport.value;

        switch ( requestType ) {
            case 'post':
                return axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/', {
                    title: title,
                    content: content,
                    organizeremail: organizeremail,
                    sport: sport,
                })
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(error => console.err(error));
            case 'put':
                return axios.put(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${trainingID}/`, {
                    title: title,
                    content: content
                })
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(error => console.err(error));
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Form onSubmitCapture={(event) => this.handleFormSubmit(
                event,
                this.props.requestType,
                this.props.trainingID)}>
              <FormItem label="Pealkiri">
                <Input name="title" placeholder="..." />
              </FormItem>
              <FormItem label="Spordiala">
                <Select name="sport" defaultValue="lucy" style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <Option value="jooks" >Jooks</Option>
                    <Option value="jõud" >Jõud</Option>
                    <Option value="crossfit" >Crossfit</Option>
                    <Option value="kardio" >Kardio</Option>
                </Select>
              </FormItem>
              <FormItem label="Kirjeldus">
                <Input name="content" placeholder="..." />
              </FormItem>
              <FormItem label="Teie (treeningu korraldaja) email">
                <Input name="organizeremail" placeholder="..." />
              </FormItem>
              <FormItem>
                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" shape="round" >
                  {this.props.btnText}
                </Button>
              </FormItem>
            </Form>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CustomForm;
```

Under "sport" i should get my selected value, but it doesn't happen.

Comment: where are you updating the state of sport value ?

Comment: how should i do it then?

Comment: you should update the sport state on select change, handleChange should be inside your class which will then update the state of sport value

Comment: handleChange = (event, value) => {
        sport = event.target.elements.sport.value;
    }

Comment: is this wrong or how should i execute it?